# Unity - MRTK - Using more than one Collider/Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

**Overview**

I downloaded the HoloToolkit-Examples-Package and tried to understand how buttons work. So I created a cube with one Button on the top. If I press the button, the cube should do some animations. All this works fine, but now I want to have two buttons on the cube and I noticed that the "Compund Button"-scripts has a fixed hierarchy/structure.

**Expected Behavior**

Every collider should do his own work

**Actual Behavior**

So my problem is that the colliders in my child triggers the same animation like the collider in the parent.

**What I did**

Here is a image of the cube [image]
What I did was:

**Parent** -> Button (made out of a cube) with the scripts Compound Button, Compound Button Mesh, Compound Button Anim..

**Child** -> Cube and another Button (made out of a cube)

Why I didnt choose the hierarchy "Parent: Cube" and "Child: Two Buttons"? Because by putting compound scripts on childs, they cant access the parent. For example pressing the button will trigger an animation with "Compund Button Anim", so the cube rotates. But I cant reference the cube, because its the parent.

Answer (score 2):

In receiver you get a gameobject this can access it's parent by gameobject.transform.parent